# Get row count of all tables in database: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to familiarize myself with a large database and search for relevant information among the many tables. I often find myself calling up a table, to see if there is relevant data inside, only to find that the table has no records.

How to quickly call up a list of all tables and the number of records contained therein? I'm using sql server 2008.

Thanks!

Related Question: [How do I QUICKLY check many sql database tables and views to see if they are not empty or contain records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066013/how-do-i-quickly-check-many-sql-database-tables-and-views-to-see-if-they-are-not)

Comment: Check out this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Looks like the sys.partitions table is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: The solution I was looking for was: SELECT t.name, p.rows FROM sys.table t JOIN sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.object_id

Comment: I think that you should put this as an answer than a comment because I was also looking for the same thing and there are chances that people might skip the comment. Cheers and thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right click on database -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Disk usage by Top Tables

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How to query it? I would prefer to be able to filter the results according to my needs.

Comment: That's not what your original question asks....

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use a query, you can use this (note: it's using an undocumented stored procedure `sp_msforeachtable`):

```
create table #tempcount (tablename nvarchar(128), record_count bigint)
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'insert #tempcount select ''?'', count(*) from ? with (nolock)'
select * from #tempcount
drop table #tempcount
```