# Query with Group by across all tables in database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database (lets call it DB) containing 150+ tables, (eg: table1, table2 etc.)

**Problem**

```
I want to loop through all tables and get count of rows by groups, as below
```

**Current Approach**

```
As of now I was thinking of appending all tables or doing so manually!
```

**Table structure**

```
name code
A    code1
A    code2
A    code6
A    code98
B    code1
```

**Expected Output**

```
table_name name code   count
table1     A    code1  100
table1     B    code2  941
table2     A    code1  98
```

**Code for each table**

```
SELECT name, code, count (*) AS count 
FROM table1
GROUP BY name, code
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get row count of all tables in database: SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548938/get-row-count-of-all-tables-in-database-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want result a single result set, below will work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
tableName VARCHAR(100)
,name VARCHAR(10)
,code VARCHAR(10)
, [Count] INT
)

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable @command1=" insert into #Temp select '?' AS tableName,Name,Code,count(*) from ? group by Name, Code"

SELECT * FROM #Temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Just as an alternative, using dynamic sql:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
tableName VARCHAR(100)
,name VARCHAR(10)
,Code VARCHAR(10)
, [Count] INT
)

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE type ='U'

OPEN tableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @TableName


WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)= N'select @table as TableName, Name, Code,Count(*) as [Count] from  '+  @tablename + ' Group by Name, Code'
INSERT INTO #Temp
EXEC sp_executesql @Query,  N'@table varchar(100)', @table = @TableName
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @TableName

END
CLOSE tableCursor
DEALLOCATE tableCursor
SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Thank you for this, if its not too much to ask (will be happy to upvote) can you tell if what if I want to query only selected table, like run query only for table1, table46, table 23 etc.

Comment: you can filter required tables while setting up your cursor. `SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE type ='U' AND name IN ('table1', 'table46', 'table 23')`

Comment: No worries. You can achieve the same with `EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable @command1=' insert into #Temp select ''?'' AS tableName,Name,Code,count(*) from ? group by Name, Code'
, @whereand = ' And Object_id In (Select Object_id From sys.tables Where name in (''temp1'', ''temp3'', ''table 23''))'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SP ForEachTable that will execute the code against each table stored in your database. Try something like this:

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1="select '?' AS TABLE_NAME,count(*) from ?"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try this today and let you know!